# Is it possible to return a custom page in varnish not using the vcl_error hook?

Tags: caching, varnish

If a specific requests comes in I would like varnish to return a page with a timestamp in it. (the client can not read headers). I see in default.vcl that vcl_error can return a custom error page. The page I want to return is not an error page. So is it possible to return a custom page from another hook in varnish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think varnish has any functionality for that. You could either use ESI (sounds like overkill, but a timestamp-serving back-end would then be used) or write a small piece of inline-C code to create the timestamp in the response body for you.